# Установка модулей в Python на Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

Я хочу установить модуль PyOWM в Python 3, но система устанавливает его в Python 2.7, помогите решить проблему

Comment: pip3 install имямодуля. Решение находится в две секунды.

Comment: Простой ответ таков, используете `pip3`. Сложный ответ: используйте окружение, например anaconda, venv

Comment: Ещё проще решение удалить Python 2

Comment: @Александр Чего уж там, можно сразу `rm -rf`. Вы, удаляя [tag:python-2.x], сразу пол системы снесёте.

Comment: А что  Ubuntu от Python сильно зависима?

Comment: @Александр А Вы попробуйте :) В кратце, да. Ни в коем случае нельзя трогать системный `Python`, даже чтобы обновиться. Необходимо устанавливать нужный `Python` отдельно.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `pip3`, вместо `pip`.

***Пример:***

```
pip3 install module_name
```

---

Или же создайте виртуальное окружение и работайте в нём.

***Пример:***

```
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install module_name
```

---

P. S.:
Благодарности участникам: [@Эникейщик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/282277/%D0%AD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA), [@hedgehogues](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/188116/hedgehogues).